# Cannot locate spring-jee.xsd file

Tags: spring, jar, xsd

I am new to Spring. Can someone please tell me in which jar file is the XSD file spring-jee.xsd located?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is in the spring context: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/resources/org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find it - its located in the spring-context jar file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help keeping all questions and answers well organized, could you please mark this question as closed - since it has been definitely been answered. You should see a "Close" link at the bottom of the question, below the tags.